# Why does a call to BeginPaint() always generate a WM_NCPAINT message?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm facing a problem on the Win32 API. I have a program that, when it handles `WM_PAINT` messages, it calls `BeginPaint` to clip the region and validate the update region, but the `BeginPaint` function is always generating a `WM_NCPAINT` message with the same update region, even if the touched part that needs repainting is only inside the client region.

Do anyone has any clue why this is happening? It's on child windows with the `WS_CHILD` style.

Comment: Can you explain in detail why is this causing you a problem?

Comment: Mostly performance, because it is generating a frame repaint even if the frame isn't dirty. I have a widget set with a kind of CSS box model and I use the frame to do the margin, border and padding.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN entry for WM_PAINT says:

> The function **may** also send the `WM_NCPAINT` message to the window procedure if the window frame must be painted and send the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message if the window background must be erased.

I'm trying to figure out why it is always sending even if the border isn't touched. I test that opening a small Notepad inside the control and minimizing. It doesn't touch the borders of the control, just inside and `BeginPaint()` generates a `WM_NCPAINT`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `WM_NCPAINT` message is always sent with the assumption that the border needs to be repainted as well!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you call `SetWindowPos` and pass `SWP_DEFERERASE` as argument for the `uFlags` parameter?

This should prevent generation of the `WM_SYNCPAINT` message, which would indirectly cause the `WM_NCPAINT` message to be sent.

Comment: Window message spy shows that WM_SYNCPAINT isn't being generated. The problem happens when the window became dirty (something is over it and needs redraw when it's gone) and not from resizing. I'm thinking in forgetting BeginPaint() and getting the DC by myself and validating the region by "hand".